# Override a function for using online URL rather than local asset

Tags: java, android

I have a function in an sdk where it strictly uses file from asset folder. I want to use the file from online. When I am passing the filename as `example.mbtiles` it is searching for the file is Asset folder and if found the app working fine. But when I am trying to get the file from a url such as `www.myurl.com/example.mbtiles` its taking all the url as string and finding the file in Asset folder which makes the app not working. Here is the function

```
private File getFile(String url, final Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            //we assume asset here
            AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream;
            try {
                inputStream = am.open(url);
                final File mbTilesDir;
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())
                        || (!Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable())) {
                    mbTilesDir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), url);
                } else {
                    mbTilesDir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), url);
                }
                return createFileFromInputStream(inputStream, mbTilesDir.getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "MBTiles file not found in assets: " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
        }
        try {
            return new File(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "can't load MBTiles: " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can I get the file from online url instead of local asset folder? what changes I need to do in this code? I also want to know, can I override this function in my MainActivity?

Comment: You'd have to completely rewrite the function to be asynchronous, make a network request for the file, and either write it to disk or parse it in memory from the result directly.  Your existing code isn't easily changed into it.  I suggest you look up some networking tutorials, there's hundreds of them online.

Comment: The file can not be parse into memory. Its huge in size.

Comment: Then write it to disk.  Doesn't change the answer-  this code needs to be totally replaced, there isn't a drop in replacement.  Do some research on networking in Android.